# Foreach loop with a pointer

Tags: c++

I have this constructor

```
class Vertex
{
    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();

    Edge* adjacencies;
};
```

I wanted there to be **array** of adjacencies, but it couldn't build. So I've created **a pointer** (Edge is my created class too).

And I have this piece of code with **foreach loop that must iterate on all adjacencies**, but, of course, it not compiles.

```
Vertex getted_vertex = vertexQueve.top();
for(Edge & e: getted_vertex.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = Vertex(e._idFrom);
            }
```

Should I change the constructor or the loop?

Comment: Use `std::vector` and you can have everything you want from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();

    std::vector<Edge> adjacencies;
    // or std::vector<Edge*> adjacencies;
};
```

Fill it like that:

```
Vertex vertex;
vertex.adjacencies.push_back( Edge() );
// or vertex.adjacencies.push_back( new Edge() );
```

Later, to iterate on adjacencies:

```
Vertex vertex;
for ( std::vector<Edge>::const_iterator edge = vertex.adjacencies.begin();
      // or std::vector<Edge*>::const_iterator edge = vertex.adjacencies.begin();
      edge != vertex.adjacencies.end();
      ++edge )
{
    Edge& edgeRef = *edge;
    // simply use edgeRef

    // or Edge* edgePtr = *edge;
}
```

If storing `Edge*` in the `vector`, you may need to `delete` them from `Vertex` destructor.

Comment: You can still use a foreach / range for here as the OP wishes.

Answer (score 2):

You need your constructor and destructor to be `public` and a container for your edges, something like:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
private:
    vector<Edge> adjacencies;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, you have to place destructor, constructor in the public space and "adjancencies" in the private space. to create a dynamic array, you have to take its size first. then use this statement:

adjancencies = new Edge[i]l; // i refers to the size of the dynamic 1D array.