# Foreach loop an atribute pointer of a class

Tags: c++, c++17

I have followed the solution given in the question of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383214/foreach-loop-with-a-pointer), but I can't get it to work for my case.

I have the following

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template<class type>
class Array {
  private:
    int size;
    pair<int,type>* base;
    
  public:
    Array() {}
    Array(int min, int max, type v) {
      size = max+min;
      base = new pair<int,type>[size];
      
      for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        base[i] = pair<int,type>(min+i,v);
    } 

    ~Array() { delete [] base; }
    



    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Array& a) {
      for(auto& b: a.base) {
        os << "{key: " << setw(3) << b.first << "} {value: " << b.second << "}" << endl;
      }
      return os;
    }
};
```

But the loop failed me when trying to iterate `base`,
I want to do it with the classic array, without using the `vector` of the stl

```sh
main.cpp:37:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::pair*&)’
   37 |       for(auto& b: a.base) {
      |       ^~~
```

Comment: `std::pair*` is not a collection, it's a pointer. Consider using `std::vector<std::pair<int,type>> base;`. Anyway `std::vector` makes `Array` odd.

Comment: you can do `for (auto& b: std::span(a.base, static_cast<std::size_t>(a.size)))` in C++20

Comment: The class is not following the rule of five, so it has all kinds of issues. Don't use raw `new` and `delete` anymore in modern C++. Use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @康桓瑋 `std::span(a.base, static_cast<std::size_t>(a.size))` is a little wordy. I would use `std::span(a.base, a.base+a.size)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop with a raw pointer, as there is no information available to the compiler about the size of the array the pointer is pointing at.  Range-for loops only work with fixed arrays and containers which support begin/end iterators, like `std::vector`, which you should be using instead of `new[]`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class type>
class Array {
  private:
    vector<pair<int,type>> base;
    
  public:
    Array() = default;

    Array(int min, int max, type v) : base(max+min) {
      for(auto& elem : base) 
        elem = make_pair(min++, v);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Array& a) {
      for(auto& elem: a.base) {
        os << "{key: " << setw(3) << elem.first << "} {value: " << elem.second << "}" << endl;
      }
      return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, the most I can narrow it down if I want to use [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is an `std::allocator` of `<memory>` library of stl right? Because I can't iterate over pointer, and if I declare an array whose size is known at compile time or const, then I can't resize it.

Comment: @Kaerit `std::allocator` has nothing to do with looping.